# Losing modality of ShowMessage window

Tags: delphi

I use `TAcroPDF` activeX control to print pdf documents. Application prints page, but if it needs to print 2 pages, it prints the first page, then shows message dialog, which asks user to turn the paper and then it prints the second page. The concept is pretty straightforward, but for unknown cause it fails to run normally. It really prints the first page, but then blips ShowMessage window (hides instantly) and the application goes seemingly on. I can then recover lost Showmessage window hidden behind the main application window, but (what is strange) I can easily change focus between showmessage window and main application. It looks like the program runs in other thread, because of ActiveX??? When I click on "OK" button, the code after `ShowMessage('Please, turn the page');` is executed. Can anybody tell me whats is going on? Here is example:

```
procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
acrpdf1.src := Getcurrentdir + '\temp.pdf';
acrpdf1.PrintAll;
ShowMessage('Please, turn the page'); //it does not hover over main window, it hides behind
Form1.Color:=clRed;  //it is executed after closing Showmessage window
end;
```

Comment: Try using MessageBox API and specify the handle of owner window with `MB_APPLMODAL` flag.

Comment: @kobik : much much better... dialog hovers over application, but still I can change focus between app and messagebox...

Comment: May be MB_SYSTEMMODAL or MB_SETFOREGROUND or MB_TOPMOST?
http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/notactive_modal.htm

Comment: @Lumen  No, it does not work...

Comment: Does this actually have anything to do with the print operation? Remove the printing code and see what happens to your dialog box.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: Yes, it has direct connection to printing operation and I am afraid, that this OLE embedding do some obscure damage...